# Get the address of an object that has overloaded operator&

Tags: c++, com, generic-programming

`operator&` for `CComPtr` is overloaded, which makes my generically written code crash.

I am wondering if there is any way to force a variable into returning the address of it's object?

Comment: You might want to rephrase this.

Comment: I've never worked with COM, but is there a base class of `CComPtr` that has no overloaded operator? You could cast the `CComPtr`to this class, take the address, and cast it back. Or, if you really want to mess things up, you could do a `&reinterpret_cast<int>(theCComPtr)`. But that is not something that I would recommend doing.

Comment: @Mike Seymour provided an answer that has later been removed due to a comment of mine. After looking at the implementation of boost::addressof, I believe that his answer is correct, should not have been removed and should be accepted.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore There, done. I was having a little nerdrage, my apologies :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is hideous:

```
reinterpret_cast<CComPtr*>(&reinterpret_cast<char&>(ptr))
```

Comment: The problem is that it is generic code, so it needs to work for any type.

Comment: I am not a windows developer, but this seems like quite dangerous. For example, if the `ptr` refers to a subobject of a complete object or if `CComPtr` is a virtual base of the complete type I can see this breaking in horrible ways...

Comment: @xcrypt: Presumably, the type is available (as a template parameter or whatever) - substitute that for `CComPtr`.

Answer (score 2):

If you can use boost, consider using: [addressof](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/utility/utility.htm#addressof), if you cannot, take a look at the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You could cast the `CComPtr` to a `CComPtrBase`, which, from what I can gather from the MSDN page, has no overloaded operator. It might look like this:

```
CComPtr* addr=dynamic_cast<CComPtr*>(&((CComPtrBase)theCComPtr));
```

I don't know if this works (I can't try it), but it seems like it might, and if it does, it's a little bit better then the `reinterpret_cast` solution.

Comment: Casting to `CComPtrBase` will invoke the copy constructor. Probably not what you want. Also, you cannot apply the `&` operator to rvalues, so this should not even compile.

Comment: Ah. Whoops. I've never used COM, so I'm working on some limited C++ knowledge here.